# Why jQuery .width() and .css( "width" ) produces different width in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I set `width:100px;` (*just for testing purposes*) in CSS, all the browsers alert as `100-100px` which is fine however when I remove `width:100px;` (*because the content is always in different lengths*) in CSS, IE result is either less or more about a few **pixels** than the other browsers.

Any idea why it is happening?

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clickhere">CLICK HERE</div>

<div id="login">This is login box</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#clickhere').click(function(event)
    {
        alert($('#login').width() + '-' + $('#login').css( "width" ));
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#login
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    right: 0px;
    /*width:100px;*/
    top: 21px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

Comment: The reason is that *it is IE*.. :)

Comment: IE 9 but there are many people who are using it for my system.

Comment: The real question is: Why does this matter to you? You may be able to answer your own question just by [looking at the jQuery source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.width)

Comment: The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation. http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Try using `.outerWidth()`

Comment: Possible dupes: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608642/why-does-jquery-csswidth-return-different-values-in-different-browsers ; (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700843/jquery-width-giving-different-values-on-chrome-and-firefox